# jQuery, nextUntil(), if element is not a paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, nextuntil

I wanna use `nextUntil()` to make all p's orange which are directly following a `h2.first` till any other html tag than p arrives.

```
<h2 class="first">Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
<h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

So in this case the pragraphs are followed by an unordered list. But it could also be any other html tag.
My problem is to express "any other html tag than p". Is there someone out there, who knows the answer?

-> `nextUntil(**'any other html tag than p'**, 'p')`

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) can help you to do so. You can use this :

```
nextUntil(":not(p)");
```

Comment: Aaaah, thanks a lot! I already tried nextUntil(:not('p'), 'p'), but it didn't work. Now I'm happy. :)